# Python. How to delete file after its been moved/copied?

Tags: python, shutil

I want a zip in source_dir to be copied/moved to dst location. The zip gets copied to the dist path. However, how do I get rid of the source_dir file? I tried move option, which removed the source_dir file but move command can't move a zip if theres a zip with a existing name. The copy method works and simply overwrites it but leaves a zip in source_dir.  Below is my code, it copies successfully but zip file does not get removed from source_dir. What am I doing wrong?

```
  def Movezips(self, email):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("starting moving")
        source_dir = 'C:/Download'+email+'/'
        dst = 'E:/BackUpZip/'+email
        Path(dst).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        dst=dst+'/'
        files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_dir, "*.zip"))
        for file in files:
             if os.path.isfile(file):
                shutil.copy(file, dst)

        for file in files:
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                shutil.rmtree(file)
```

Comment: " but move command can't move a zip if theres a zip with a existing name." huh?

Comment: Sorry I meant   shutil.move(file, dst) can move zip from source to dst, without leaving a copy in source folder. But fails if the there is a zip already with the same name in dst.

Comment: Just a general piece of advice, try to use `pathlib.Path`, you're mixing `os` a lot, but stick to one or the other. In any case, on windows, you have to `remove` a file if it already exists before trying to `move` to that name. You can do this with `os.rename` and `os.remove` or, using `target = Path(target); target.unlink(); source.move(target)` where `source` is some `Path` object

Answer (score 0):

You can use os instead of shutil to remove folders and files

To remove a file you can use `os.remove("filename")`

To remove a folder you can use `os.rmdir("foldername")`

Or using shutil you could try

'shutil.move(file, dst, copy_function=copy)'

the default `copy_function` for move is `copy2`, but as you say `copy` works for you this maybe also work

Comment: You should probably use the more modern `pathlib` instead of the clunky `os` module.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix the issue I had. Simply removed the extra code in the end.

```
files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_dir, "*.zip"))
        for file in files:
             if os.path.isfile(file):
                shutil.copy(file, dst)
                os.remove(file)
```